# Use of break inside nested for loop

Tags: for-loop, nested-loops, break

```
for(int i =o;i<n;i++)
{   // loop 1
    for(int j =0;j<n;j++)
    {       //loop 2
          for(int k =0;k<n;k++)
          {     // loop 3
                .........
                break;
          }
     }
 }
```

MY question is: will the break statement break the loop 3 by getting out of the loop 3 and fall into loop 2 and continue the execution of loop 2. Or the break statement will get out of all 3 loops and fall outside of loop 1 and execute the loop 1 afterward statements?

Comment: In most C-like languages a `break;` statement only breaks the directly surrounding loop, though without specifying the language it would theoretically be possible to be some obscure language that behaves differently

Comment: You might consider editing the title to show what language you are using, or at least add a tag for it.  The behavior may depend on it.  That being said... don't do this.  It's confusing to read and difficult to maintain.  Split the for loops into separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

When a break statement is encountered inside a loop, the loop is immediately terminated and the program control resumes at the next statement following the loop.  Thus, the break in loop 3 will drop execution to loop 2.